# How can I update model from change event of meteor view?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a meteor application. It has a simple data model, and edit screen. The model is following:

```
{
   _id: "some_id",
   date: "date",
   attempts: [{k1: "v1"}, {k1: "v2"}, {k1: "v1"}]
}
```

This model is stored in session. Edit screen is organasied in the following way:

```
<template name="editModel">
    <form>
        {{#each model.attempts}}
            {{> attempt}}
            <hr/>
        {{/each}}
    </form>
    <button class="btn add-rep">Add</button>
    <hr/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-exercise">Submit</button>
</template>

<template name="attempt">
    <label>K1</label>
    <select name="k1">
        <option {{selected k1 "1"}} >1</option>
        <option {{selected k1 "2"}} >2</option>
    </select>
</template>
```

The `attempt` template basically is just dropdown, that should update `k1` property of object. I wrote following code:

```
function keyChanged (e, t){
    t.data.k1 = t.find("[name='k1']").value;
}

Template.attempt.events = {
    "change select[name='grip']"    : keyChanged
}
```

But it does not work, because `data` is read only. The question is: how can I update that object inside `attempts` array?

Answer (score 1):

You've not given enough detail on your collection to go on, but you would update your collection directly to change your model's data, or use what you're using as your model engine to do it.

E.g to update your collection directly (add something to that array):

```
Collection.update(id_of_record,{attempts : { $addToSet: {k1:"v9"} } });
```

So this would add a new record to the set. Have a look at [all the operations possible](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/), with the mongodb docs on arrays such as `$addToSet` the only thing you can't do for the moment is use the `$` positional operator

As soon as you update your collection the corresponding template data would update using reactivity. I would be a bit careful and use `{{#isolate}}` & `{{#constant}}` with your use case to ensure the data around your HTML is rendered without having the entire template redraw so. See [Reactivity Isolation](http://docs.meteor.com/#isolate) & [Constant Regions](http://docs.meteor.com/#constant)

Comment: Of course you can! Parse them as javascript objects and change them as you wish and use {`$set:{attempts:updated_attempts}}` to apply the updates

Comment: the problem, is that in change event handler, i have only part of my attempts collection, and I even don't know it's index in array.

Comment: You don't need to know the index, you can loop through the entire array without the index to find the one you want and alter it, then use this new updated array with `$set` so it updates your collection

Comment: Perhaps you can give me an idea of what you want to update and how so that I can give an example?

Comment: attempts view has one combobox that should update property `k1` of an object, in attempts array. There could be several objects in that array (in fact, parent view has ADD button). And there sever "attempts" view inside parent view. It is not clear how to update specific object inside array in change event handler :(

Comment: Im a bit confused on the bit on which one in the array to update, so you're going to update k1, but which one? there are so many and if both have the same value (such as the v1) theres no way to decide which of the two to update, or will it be both? Is it going to be dependent uppon their position in the combobox?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27194/discussion-between-gor-and-akshat)